# How to make Meteor Method return result after internal function is finished with wrapAsync?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, async-await

I have Meteor method with a following fragment (below) and it has asynchronous loop inside. As far as i know, this should be wrapped with meteor wrapAsync, but their documentation isn't clear enough to me, so i'm not sure how to implement it properly. What would be the easiest way to use wrapAsync on this example?

```
if(Meteor.isServer){

  Meteor.methods({
    listCollections: function(){

      // list collections in database
      db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;
      collections = db.listCollections();

      // convert cursor with collections to javascript array:

      // method should wait for this loop to finish before returning result
      var collectionsArray = [];
      collections.each(function(n, collection){
          if(collection){
              collectionsArray.push(collection.name);
          }
      });

      // return ignores the each loop and empty array is passed as a result
      return collectionsArray;

    }
  });

  Meteor.call("listCollections", function(err, res){
    console.log(res);
  });

}
```

Comment: Look at the promises.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to understand from your context, but normally, the `wrapAsync` could be used like this

```
Meteor.methods({ 
    'yourCurrentMethod': function(sentCollections) {
        var processArray = function (collections) {
            var collectionsArray = [];

            collections.each(function(n, collection){
                if(collection){
                    collectionsArray.push(collection.name);
                }
            });

            // return ignores the each loop and empty array is passed as a result
            return collectionsArray;  
        };

        var processArrayCalling = Meteor.wrapAsync(processArray);
        var result = processArrayCalling(sentCollections); 

        // process with the result
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, I tried to test your code with my method, but without success ( `return result;` did not return anything ), so I updated the question with full code of a method. This code does not rely on any other javascript files or functions, than default Meteor functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem using Future, which was really easy to use.

```
if(Meteor.isServer){

  var Future = Npm.require( 'fibers/future' ); // future code

  Meteor.methods({
    listCollections: function(){

      // list collections in database
      db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;
      collections = db.listCollections();

      // create our future instance
      var future = new Future(); // future code

      // count number of collections inside collection list
      var collectionsCount = 0;
      collections.each(function(n, collection){
        collectionsCount++;
      });

      // method should wait for this loop to finish before returning result
      var collectionsArray = [];
      var i = 0;
      collections.each(function(n, collection){
        if(collection){
            collectionsArray.push(collection.name);
        }
        i++;
        if( i == collectionsCount ){
          future.return( collectionsArray ); // future code
        }
      });

      return future.wait(); // future code
    }
  });

  Meteor.call("listCollections", function(err, res){
    console.log(res);
  });

}
```